# QnAmaker bot Azure AD Authentication not working

Tags: azure, botframework

I created a QnAmaker bot and i enabled Azure AD authentication to make the bot more secure.

The Azure AD page works, i can enter my credentials and i get redirected to the page where my bot is located.

However, when i send a message, it doesn't arrive. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnh4y.jpg

The error message i get is the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Newt.jpg

In the bot logging, i see the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3JYt.jpg

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes i use the Webchat channel

Comment: Can you show us how you implemented this? It it impossible to know what is happening without having a look at the code